# Mongo '_id' field not being added in ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, elasticsearch-plugin, mongoosastic

I am using ElasticSearch and mongoosastic to sync the data between our MongoDB and ElasticSearch.

The problem I am having is that when I run a search on the data in ElasticSearch, it is not returning the '_id' property of the objects. Most likely because I am incorrectly telling it to, but I can't find any documentation.

A dummy example of the object that I am telling mongoosastic to sync to ElasticSearch from Mongo is shown below:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type:String,es_indexed:true},
        phone: {type:String,es_indexed:true},
        settings:{type:[String],es_indexed:true,index:'not_analyzed'}
}, {id: true});

userSchema.plugin(mongoosastic,settings.elasticSearch);

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
    if(err){
        console.log('error creating User mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('User mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
```

When I run a **_search** on ElasticSearch, I get results with the following structure

```
    {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "54b3ea9619160d0b0080d751",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "John Smith",
           "phone": "JohnSmith@gmail.com",
           "settings": []
        }
     }
```

Any ideas how to get the _id of the mongo object into the _source object?

Comment: Do you actually need it in the `_source`? Is `"_id": "54b3ea9619160d0b0080d751"` not the relevant ID?

Comment: It is an old post, but to people who want to know, no need to have an id in the `_source` object. The `_id` should be the relevant id. If it is not the case, your mongodb and elasticsearch are not in sync. If you check mongoosastic source code for hydratation, they are using this `_id` to retrieve data from mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Elasticsearch does not index or store the id field by default:

> **_id**
>
> Each document indexed is associated with an id and a type. The _id
>   field can be used to index just the id, and possible also store it. By
>   default it is not indexed and not stored (thus, not created).
>
> The _id field can be enabled to be indexed, and possibly stored, using
>   the appropriate mapping attributes:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_id" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

The issue will be how to pass the "store": true parameters into the createMapping function of mongoosastic. You may need to play around a bit with the createMapping function, modify the code on your own or try to create the Elasticsearch mapping by hand prior to indexing any data.